# Will Minecraft 1.9 pre-release map seeds be changed in the final version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to make a new map in 1.9, but I'm not sure if the seed will change and the biomes be corrupted like it was in 1.8. Does anyone know if it will?

Comment: The map seeds never change. The terrain generator occasionally does, though.

Comment: I can't remember where it is, but I distinctly remember it saying *Don't get too attached to your save file* on minecraft.net! I'd wait until final 1.0 before making your be-all-and-end-all world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, it's not the map seeds that change, it's the terrain generator. And while I don't know for certain, I'll say this: **It's very likely.**

Each new feature that is generated with the world requires an update to the terrain generator. Counting on the fact that after 1.9, it will never change again… well, it probably will.

Specifically, the 1.9 pre-release introduced some pretty big changes to terrain generation (mostly in the Nether), so it will probably be tweaked for the 1.9 beta.

Comment: Temper with this with the fact that there were biome changes between 1.8 and 1.9 which is why things got shifted a bit (the land looks the same but the Biome it is is different). No new biome changes have been announced to be forthcoming as 1.9 was supposed to have finished them up (including the super rare mushroom biome!)

Comment: I'd actually say it is very likely for the exact reason you say it will not. "the 1.9 pre-release introduced some pretty big changes to terrain generation" If they find a bug/balance issue they would get it fixed before the pre-release is released. That could cause tearing on your newly generated areas. And it may not be obvious, it could be something like the frequency of spawning a stronghold.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's really what I'm saying, or at least what I wanted to say.

Comment: @lunboks Wow, I do not know why, but I read your post as "It's **NOT** very likely." I need sleep.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The formatting puts the "not" from the previous line in-between the "it's" and "very likely", so that would probably explain it.